# ¿Cómo incluir posts/páginas y demás contenido a una theme de WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, theme

Estoy terminando mi primera theme de WordPress y quería saber si hay alguna manera de incluir en la carpeta de la propia theme las entradas, páginas, thumbnails y demás elementos que yo he ido añadiendo en el administrador de WordPress.

Sería para que cuando yo le facilite la theme al cliente, éste pueda modificar las cosas sin tener que crearlas desde cero.

Gracias por vuestra atención, un cordial saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es mantener todas las opciones de la web que le has creado a tu cliente deberás facilitarle la base de datos exportada que habrás generado y que es donde se guarda la información de las entradas, páginas y demás elementos.

Respecto a las imágenes y thumbnails hay algunos plugins que te permiten cambiar la carpeta de destino de las imágenes que subes mediante el administrador, por ejemplo este [plugin](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/upload-url-path-enabler/). Lo instalas y seleccionas la carpeta de tu tema, así podrás facilitarle solo a tu cliente el tema y la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Cómo se exporta la base de datos? ¿Y cómo la añadiría al proyecto?

Muchas gracias por la respuesta.